# iOS: how to run XCTest on device?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xctest

I currently learning XCTest for the purpose of unit testing. I was able to run the default template XCtest on the simulator without any problem. I could all the green ticks in the test navigation view. However, when I ran them on the device with my app as host application, nothing happens. My app was launched on the device and the XCTest did not seem to run. I even put a break point in the test and it did not break. Also, in the simulator, the app automatically stops when tests finish, however, when running on device, my app was just kept running and never put to a stop. Am I doing something incorrect?

Answer (score 4):

xCode should show this message when running XCTest on a physical device.

> Logic Testing on iOS devices is not supported. You can run logic tests on the Simulator.

Comment: It did at first, however, once I choose my app as the host application and tick the "Allow testing Host Application APIs" box, it went aways.

Comment: In Xcode 6, it could run test in device, just making sure that a valid provisioning profile was set to test target is ok, I used wildcard one and ran  great.

Answer (score 3):

There's a library called GHUnit we can run unit tests on iphone device. Internally it uses xctest. Here is how you setup GHUnit.

I was able to follow the instructions and setup unit tests using xcode 5. should be okay with Xcode 6?

Comment: I'm assuming your device UDID is added to ur provisioning profile??

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will definitely give a go at the GHUint. As for the provision profile, I did create a specific provision profile for the test target otherwise the build would fail.

Comment: Is the devise your testing on the provisioning profile? Set the code singing and provisioning profile to automatic, play around with it a but and see how it works. I recommend keeping the provisioning profile settings to automatic.