# Beginning Unit Testing in Xcode

Tags: xcode, unit-testing

I decided to dive into learning how to create unit tests in Xcode, but I am not getting expected results when trying to perform a test.

I created a new project in Xcode 7 and the test targets were created for me when I created the project. After following a tutorial, I realized that I am not seeing the same thing as I am from the tutorial.

I have an `XCTestCase` subclass:

[image]

However, when I click the run button next to either of the bottom methods, I always receive the "Test Succeeded" notification, but neither of the methods show a green checkmark or red "x". One of the methods was built to succeed, while the other was built to fail. Also, when clicking the run button next to the subclass, the exact same thing happens.

It seems as though something isn't set up correctly, but I don't even know where to begin finding the issue.

Is there something obvious from the screenshot that I am missing?

Comment: How about using cmd-U to run the tests instead? It is possible that there is a build issue that will get cleared up by doing that.

Comment: @ThomasW I created a new project, per matt's advice, and it worked fine. Then, I tried again in my current project, using ⌘+U. While using the simulator, it worked. It does not work when using my device. I wasn't aware that it won't work on my device so I will just stick to using the simulator.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think Xcode has ever supported unit testing with devices. (You may have success [using GHUnit though](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29077475/211292).)

Answer (score 0):

I followed your instructions, creating a completely new project and copying the code from your screenshot, and this is what I see:

[image]

The only thing I can think of to suggest is that you try building and running your app target code first. The reason is that seeing nothing at all, as in your screen shot, is what I would expect if it wasn't possible to build and run.

(The fact that a warning shows in your screen shot is interesting; you might want to start by tracking that down.)

If that doesn't help, maybe you should start over with a new project...?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using CocoaPods to manage Alamofire & SwiftyJSON. Would having to use the ```.xcworkspace``` have anything to do with it?

Comment: I haven't the slightest idea. :)

Comment: But do follow my suggestion of doing this _in a vanilla new project_. You will then see that it works. That will put your mind at ease and you can take it from there.